# Como alterar apenas uma parte dentro de xml usando php?

Tags: php, xml

estou com uma certa dificuldade para chegar a essa conclusao.
Vou exemplicar, tenho o xml ficticio abaixo:

`<url>http://www.example.com/TITULO<url/>`

Quero alterar apenas a parte titulo, no caso ficando assim:

`<url>http://www.example.com/OUTROTITULO<url/>`

Alguma ideia de como fazer essa mudança. Nao quero modificar tudo, apenas a parte destacada em maiusculo.

Comment: Depende de um monte de coisas que você não informou. Eis algumas (das várias) que fazem diferença: É sempre na mesma tag que vai estar a informação a ser trocada? É uma troca só, ou são várias? É sempre a mesma string original, ou pode mudar? Procure por o máximo de detalhes possíveis, e de preferência o mais próximos da realidade do caso. Sugiro uma lida em **[ask]** e **[tour]** para melhor aproveitamento do site.

Comment: E ainda, é mesmo uma string, ou esse XML já passou por um parser?

Comment: um jeito bem rápido e grosserio é usar funções como strpos e/ou explode e substr()... Outro modo é por meio de expressão regular, mas partifularmente prefiro não usar ER para algo muito simples.

Comment: Não havendo restrições explicitas, e não sendo necessário interpretar a estrutura do arquivo XML, eu usaria apenas a função [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 1):

Existem duas classes no PHP que lhe permitirá fazer essa operação.

[`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) e [`DomDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Acho que, com a explicação do manual do PHP, não há necessidade de postar exemplos.

[Basic SimpleXML usage](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

Outra dica é que, se estiver tentando abrir o XML de um arquivo  já existente, use a função `simplexml_load_file()`;

Comment: +1; usar expressões regulares pra processar XML (ou HTML, ou SQL) é loucura.